# Nominal/categorical axis on a scatter plot

Tags: python, bokeh

How is it possible to generate a nominal/categorical axis (entries like `a, b, c` instead of `1,2,3`) on a scatter plot in Bokeh?

Imagine that the following data should be plotted:

```
a  0.5
b  10.0
c  5.0
```

I tried the following:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk

# output to static HTML file
bk.output_file("scatter.html", title="scatter plot example")

x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [0.5, 10.0, 5.0]

p = bk.figure(title = "scatter")
p.circle(x = x, y = y)
bk.show(p)
```

However, this generates an empty plot. If the `x` data is changed to `x = [1, 2, 3]` everything gets plotted as expected.

What can I do to have `a, b, c` on the x axis?

Comment: Another example you can find here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082912/bokeh-plot-with-a-nominal-or-ordinal-axis-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the list of categories as the `x_range` or `y_range` explicitly. See:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html

Answer (score 4):

Based on bigreddot's answer, `x_range` needs to be set explicitly as follows:

```
p = bk.figure(title = "scatter", x_range = x)
```

This is the complete example:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk

# output to static HTML file
bk.output_file("scatter.html", title="scatter plot example")

x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [0.5, 10.0, 5.0]

p = bk.figure(title = "scatter", x_range = x)
p.circle(x = x, y = y)
bk.show(p)
```